# Stacked column custom interval

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts stacked column graph . I want to have my custom interval spacing . I have a range [0,200] . I want to display tick marks like [0,50,60,70,80,90,100,..,200]. I have tried lots but I am not getting the desired output .
I am only getting [0,20,40,60,80,100,..180,200]. Please help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/anandabhishe/6fuffmpt/

Comment: Please post more details. What code is returning [0,50,60,70,80,90,100,..,200] ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `yAxis.tickPositions`. It is set like this:

```
yAxis: {
  tickPositions: [0,50,60,70,80,90,100,200],
  ...
}
```

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/6fuffmpt/1/